# Conflicting Nginx Server for Odoo 16 Self Hosted Website

Tags: linux, security, nginx, server, odoo-16

I have an issue with nginx setup for my self hosted Odoo 16 - which means every 3-4 weeks my nginx log is full and the server goes offline, and i have to reboot it. It also means anyone viewing [www.MYDOMAINNAME.CO.UK](http://www.MYDOMAINNAME.CO.UK) gets a warning of an insecure website as well

I think its clearly my lack of knowledge with Nginx so would appreciate any help. My gut feeling is that my nginx sites enabled file is very messy.

```
root@ubuntu-4gb-hel1-1:~# sudo nginx -t

nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored


My current sites-enabled file is:


upstream odoo16 {

server 127.0.0.1:8069;

}


upstream odoochat {

server 127.0.0.1:8072;

}


server {

server_name MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk www.MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk;

listen 80;

listen [::]:80;

return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}


server {

server_name MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk www.MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk;


add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;



access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;

error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;


proxy_buffers 16 64k;

proxy_buffer_size 128k;


location / {

proxy_pass http://odoo16;

proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

proxy_redirect off;

proxy_set_header Host $host;

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

}


location /longpolling {

proxy_pass http://odoochat;

}


location ~* /web/static/ {

proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;

proxy_buffering on;

expires 864000;

proxy_pass http://odoo16;

}


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot

ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}



server {

if ($host = MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk) {

return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

} # managed by Certbot



listen 80;

server_name MYDOMAINNAME.co.uk;

return 404; # managed by Certbot



}
```

I tried removing any duplicate blocks already but I think the above file still isn't right.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.